# Setting time out in iframe inside Ext.Window

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs, timeout

I have an `iframe` inside `ExtJS` `Ext.Window` component. In the `iframe`, I make an `ajax` call to the `php` layer, which returns a `pdf` object and that gets rendered in the `iframe`. I need to set timeout in the js layer, say if the processing takes more than 1 second, I should abort the process. I saw about the various methods that `iframe` provides, but there is nothing relating to timeout. `ontimeout` is the closest function, but I am not clear where to set the timeout.

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
    id: 'window',
    width: 290,
    height: 440,
    shim: false,
    hidden: true,
    closeAction: 'destroy',
    waitMsg: "fetching",
    html: '<iframe style="width:100%; height:100%;" src="/index.php/abc/xyz?value=' + value + '"onload =" this.contentWindow.print();this.contentWindow.close();"/>'
});
win.show();
win.hide();
```

The above piece of code is present within a function which gets called whenever the `value` is entered in a text box and Enter key is pressed.

Can someone please tell me how to set the timeout in the JavaScript file?

Comment: If you dont have any problem call ajax before opening the iframe and set the timeout function in ajax calls.

Comment: @MohammadRaheem I tried that approach too. I have asked a similar question to handle the same in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285410/accept-application-pdf-in-ext-ajax-request

Is this what you're suggesting?

Comment: I don't think there is a configurable timeout for iframes in the Web standards. It is also difficult to determine whether the iframe contents have loaded, because the load and document readystatechange events do not represent the loading state of the PDF. Therefore, it is necessary to check the contents of the document which is only allowed if the PDF is from the same origin.