# Accept application/pdf in Ext.Ajax.request

Tags: ajax, pdf, extjs

I am using `Ext.Ajax.request()` to make an API call which produces `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`. This is being handled in the `php` layer which returns the object in

`header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
 echo $response;`

The problem is, I am not able to handle the received object in the `Ext.Ajax.request()` since it always handles only Json objects by default.

I tried giving `Headers`, `AcceptType` in the request, but it always goes to the `failure` block.

Here is the code:

```
Ext.Ajax.useDefaultXhrHeader = false;
var responseText;
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/index.php/abc/xyz?value=' + value,
    method: 'GET',
    waitMsg: 'Printing Label',
    contentType: 'application/octet-stream' //not sure,
    responseType: 'blob' //not sure,
    xhr2: false //not sure,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log("Success!!");
        return "";
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        //Always comes here. The API returns 200
        console.log("Hi here in the error");
        //Raw pdf gets printed
        console.log(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: What kind of error you are getting here ...

Comment: @MohammadRaheem It is not about the error. It always goes to the failure block. I'd like to receive it in the success block or at least, I should somehow be able to decode the obtained response in the form of `application/pdf`.

Comment: Remove success and failure and handle the response in done function

Comment: @MohammadRaheem: I'd eventually handle timeout functionality like how I have mentioned in my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285225/setting-time-out-in-iframe-inside-ext-window?noredirect=1#comment87586592_50285225 and if I don't handle them in two different blocks, I can't handle the timeout/error cases right? Also, how would I even decode this response into a pdf format?

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan Can you change the return format of the API call, or is it set in stone?

Comment: @Alexander Can't change the return format of the API call :(

Answer (score 0):

> but it always goes to the failure

For this you need to check in `php` side because may be something you have missed. I think may be this will help you [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Try with this code. Hope this will help/guide you to get required result.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/index.php/abc/xyz?value=' + value,
    method: 'GET',
    waitMsg: 'Printing Label',
    cors: true,
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    withCredentials: true,
    defaultHeaders: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream;'
    },
    timeout:0,//If don't know how time will take server to get the file then you can put 0. if you need 
    success: function(response) {
        //In response you will directly get the octet-stream

        //For showing pdf in front end side using blob url
        var byteCharacters = atob(response.responseText),
            len = byteCharacters.length,
            byteNumbers = new Array(len),
            key = 0,
            byteArray,
            blob,
            contentType = 'application/pdf';

        //insert charcter code in {byteNumbers}
        for (; key < len; key++) {
            byteNumbers[key] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(key);
        }
        //convert {byteNumbers} into Uint8Array
        byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        //create blob using {byteArray}
        blob = new Blob([byteArray], {
            type: contentType
        });
        // set {src} to {iframe}
        window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob), '_blank');
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        //if somthing wrong in serverside then it will come in failure.
    }
});
```

Hope this will also help you for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285225/setting-time-out-in-iframe-inside-ext-window#50285225) as well.